# spring boot mysql jpa Command Line Runner problem

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, jpa

I want to create a user within the run () method using CommandLineRunner. I want to automatically call this method and register it with JPA as soon as Tomcat runs. Below I share the codes I use within the project.When I ran it this way, the tomcat server worked fine, the system started but was not registered to the database. How do I fix this?

**User**

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "user_id")
    private int id;
    @Column(name = "email")
    @Email(message = "*Please provide a valid Email")
    @NotEmpty(message = "*Please provide an email")
    private String email;
    @Column(name = "password")
    @Length(min = 5, message = "*Your password must have at least 5 characters")
    @NotEmpty(message = "*Please provide your password")
    private String password;
    @Column(name = "name")
    @NotEmpty(message = "*Please provide your name")
    private String name;
    @Column(name = "last_name")
    @NotEmpty(message = "*Please provide your last name")
    private String lastName;
    @Column(name = "active")
    private int active;
    //JOIN tables
    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "user_role", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id"))
    private Set<Role> roles;

    public User() {};

    public User(String email, String password, String name, String lastName, int active) {
        this.email=email;
        this.password=password;
        this.name=name;
        this.lastName=lastName;
        this.active=active;
    }

    //G&S
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }
    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }
    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }
    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
    public int getActive() {
        return active;
    }
    public void setActive(int active) {
        this.active = active;
    }
    public Set<Role> getRoles() {
        return roles;
    }
    public void setRoles(Set<Role> roles) {
        this.roles = roles;
    }
}
```

**Role**

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "role")
public class Role {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "role_id")
    private int id;
    @Column(name = "role")
    private String role;

    //G&S
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getRole() {
        return role;
    }
    public void setRole(String role) {
        this.role = role;
    }
}
```

**UserRepository**

```
@Repository("userRepository")
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {
    User findByEmail(String email);
}
```

**RoleRepository**

```
@Repository("roleRepository")
public interface RoleRepository extends JpaRepository<Role, Integer> {
    Role findByRole(String role);
}
```

**Service**

```
public class ServiceImplement implements CommandLineRunner{
    @Autowired
    UserService userService;
    @Autowired
    UserRepository userRepository; 
    @Autowired
    RoleRepository roleRepository;

    //$2y$12$YN6IjSzj5DYvSpv6jofxV.p8C.zSKKTdnDZ4oc0XT0TmODcUe.s62  =  umut1234

    User umut = null;
    Role userRole = null;

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        umut = new User();
        umut.setEmail("umut@umut.com");
        umut.setPassword("$2y$12$YN6IjSzj5DYvSpv6jofxV.p8C.zSKKTdnDZ4oc0XT0TmODcUe.s62");
        umut.setName("Umut");
        umut.setLastName("Eren");
        umut.setActive(1);
        userRole = roleRepository.findByRole("ADMIN");
        umut.setRoles(new HashSet<Role>(Arrays.asList(userRole)));
        userRepository.save(umut);

        System.out.println("***Generated***");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import org.springframework.boot.ApplicationArguments
import org.springframework.boot.ApplicationRunner

// add these 2 lines and change your impelentation to ApplicationRunner
@Component
@Order(value = 1)
public class ServiceImplement implements ApplicationRunner{
    @Autowired
    UserService userService;
    @Autowired
    UserRepository userRepository; 
    @Autowired
    RoleRepository roleRepository;

    //$2y$12$YN6IjSzj5DYvSpv6jofxV.p8C.zSKKTdnDZ4oc0XT0TmODcUe.s62  =  umut1234

    User umut = null;
    Role userRole = null;

    @Override
    public void run(ApplicationArguments args) throws Exception {
        umut = new User();
        umut.setEmail("umut@umut.com");
        umut.setPassword("$2y$12$YN6IjSzj5DYvSpv6jofxV.p8C.zSKKTdnDZ4oc0XT0TmODcUe.s62");
        umut.setName("Umut");
        umut.setLastName("Eren");
        umut.setActive(1);
//save user before add roles to it
        userRepository.save(umut);
        userRole = roleRepository.findByRole("ADMIN");
        umut.setRoles(new HashSet<Role>(Arrays.asList(userRole)));
        userRepository.save(umut);

        System.out.println("***Generated***");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class ServiceImplement implements ApplicationRunner {
          @Autowired
          UserService userService;
          @Autowired
          UserRepository userRepository;
          @Autowired
          RoleRepository roleRepository;


          User umut = null;
          Role userRole = null;

          @Override
          public void run(ApplicationArguments args) throws Exception {

            String arguments = String.join(" | ", args.getSourceArgs());
            System.out.println(arguments);
            if(args.getNonOptionArgs().contains("-register"){
              umut = new User();
              umut.setEmail("umut@umut.com");
              umut.setPassword("$2y$12$YN6IjSzj5DYvSpv6jofxV.p8C.zSKKTdnDZ4oc0XT0TmODcUe.s62");
              umut.setName("Umut");
              umut.setLastName("Eren");
              umut.setActive(1);
              userRole = roleRepository.findByRole("ADMIN");
              umut.setRoles(new HashSet<Role>(Arrays.asList(userRole)));
              userRepository.save(umut);

              System.out.println("***Generated***");
            }
          }
        }
```

Comment: In Spring boot use ApplicationRunner and pass argument -register This will help you register when running spring boot.
Check https://dzone.com/articles/spring-boot-applicationrunner-and-commandlinerunne

Comment: i change it then the console print error: start error